# Ecommerce SEO structure - Headings

Tags: seo, ecommerce, heading

I have done quite a bit of research on SEO as I have a new website (around 6 months old) and it does not feature on google for any search terms that I would associate with it other than the website name where it ranks 1st lol.

My competitors are all established websites who have been around for a number of years with a solid customer base.

I suppose the main question is... Can i compete? or do i just need to bide my time?

Currently my product page structure has the main headinh `<h1>` at the top which is the product title

The product description then contains `<h2>` - Product title and brand and then a description below...

would it make much difference if below the `<h2>` i added another `<h2>` containing the product category?

My understanding is that the better googles understanding is of my products, the quicker I can potentially increase my ranking to compete with my competitors?

Answer (score 0):

If you try uploading your mark up [at the w3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options), you will get an error if you have `<h2>` under `<h2>`. Headings should be in descending order and without gaps in their numbering (`<h2>`->`<h4>` without `<h3>` is also wrong).

If you want a better (SEO-wise) structure for your products check out [Google's rich data format for products](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product).

You are correct that better structure improves your SEO ranking and thus your chances of appearing higher in search engines's results.

Keep in mind though that at the end of the day, content is king. SEO is just something to assist you. God levels of SEO will not help you much if your content doesn't attract traffic.